# Set Consistent line spacing, irrespective of bold or underlines etc

Tags: fonts, display

I current have set the current line number face to be bold:

```
`(line-number-current-line ((,class (:foreground "#4F4F4F" :background "#00CC00" :bold t))))
```

When I move the cursor between lines, there is a very unpleasant movement of all the text, as the line with the bold text takes up a little more height, so that line gets taller, and then contracts when the cursor moves past it.

This is just a single example of where this issue is popping up. Another example is if any highlighting makes the word bold (e.g. matching parenthesis).

If I change the line spacing, there is just extra space between the lines, and bold text still expands even though there is adequate space.

Comment: Do you see the same thing with a different monospace font? If not, it may be because your particular font has taller bold chars (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Drew was right. Instead of using the default font, I downloaded a nice mono space font from Google (Roboto Mono), and that is working fine.